# Debian 12 install on dual boot laptop with Win 11 : no more Win 11 entry in UEFI/bios

Tags: linux, debian, boot, uefi

I have recently installed Debian 12 on a dual-boot laptop where Windows 11 is also installed.

After the Debian 12 installation, the laptop booted on Grub which includes Debian 12, advanced config, Windows 11 and UEFI. Debian 12 works fine.

However, I noticed in the UEFI/ Bios itself that the Windows boot manager entry is not there anymore.

Is there a way, from Linux Debian itself, to restore this entry in the UEFI/Bios so that it sees the Windows Boot Manager again.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows folder in ESP has normal boot files.

New Windows entry - assumes default sda1  add -d /dev/sda -p 2 if sda2 or NVMe example:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"

sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1
```

See also:

```
man efibootmgr
```

Best from with in Windows to create the repair/recovery flash drive, so you can make full repairs, just as you keep live installer to make repairs.

Comment: Many thanks @oldfred for responding so quickly, and your answer did the job ! :-D